# Retrieve Specific Text using Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: html, parsing, dom

Taking an example of following

```
<div id="XYZ">
   <div id ="abc"></div>  
   Text 1
   <div id="efg"> Text 2 </div>
   Text 3
</div>
```

How do I retrieve Text 1 and Text 2 using simple HTML DOM Parser.

If I use  `$text  = $domOb->find(div[id=xyz])->plaintext;`

Above will give me entire text . This thing I know but i am stuck in how to retrieve specific Text portions.

Comment: <div class="abc"> Text 1 <div class="efg"> Text2 </div> Text 3 </div>

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to work around this is by wrapping the desired text in `<span>` tags and giving that its own ID. Because span is not a block element it won't disrupt the layout of your HTML page.

Comment: Hi I cannot change the HTML over here. The portions that i have shown here are fixed. Now I am looking for way to retrieve just Text 1 or just Text 3.